# Injecting javascript with data from settings app

Tags: javascript, ios, settings, settings.bundle

I have setup a settings bundle and can successfully pull data from that. I also need to inject some code into a UIWebView which I can also successfully do. Now the question is **How do I combine the 2?**

I have this code to read a textField label from the setting bundle:

```
NSString *textField01 = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"tetxtField01_preference"];
```

and i have this string to inject code into the UIWebView:

```
 [_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('textField01').value = 'default text'"];
```

Now in the `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` I can inject the "default text" but then it is hardcoded into the app and I cannot change it within the app.

So is it possible and if so how do I put objective-c NSString in the place default text?

I was thinking of something along the lines of:

```
[_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('textField01').value = [@"%@", textField01] "];
```

but it gives an error:-)

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the Js string completely and pass it on to the "stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:" function. 
i.e

NSString *foo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementById('textField01').value = %@",textField01];
[_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:foo];